# Ubuntu Server 18.04 LVM out of space with improper default partitioning

Tags: partitioning, 18.04, lvm

I installed Ubuntu Server 18.04 with the LVM option and left the default partition setup. Now my main drive only has 4GB in a 1TB hard drive. How can I fix this without starting from scratch?

Results of `df -h` :

```
Filesystem                         Size    Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev                                16G       0       16G   0% /dev
tmpfs                               32G    1.7M       32G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv  3.9G    3.6G       92M  98% /    
tmpfs                               16G       0       16G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M       0      5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                               16G       0       16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0                          87M     87M         0 100% /snap/core/4917
/dev/loop1                         3.2M    3.2M         0 100% /snap/stress-ng/471
/dev/loop2                          90M     90M         0 100% /snap/core/6130
/dev/sda2                          976M    143M      766M  16% /boot
tmpfs                              3.2G       0      3.2G   0% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: It happens to me too, by using the "ubuntu-18.04.3-live-server-amd64.iso" instead of dedicated server iso.

Comment: exactly the same for me!

Comment: ubuntu 22.04 is out and this is still not fixed...

Comment: This actually a major issue if you don't pay attention enough..

Answer (score 279, accepted):

Had the exact same problem with a fresh install of Ubuntu Server 18.04.1.

What I had to do was:

```sh
# We need to resize the logical volume to use all the existing and free space of the volume group
$ lvm
lvm> lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv
lvm> exit

# And then, we need to resize the file system to use the new available space in the logical volume
$ resize2fs /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv
resize2fs 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
Filesystem at /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv is mounted on /; on-line resizing required
old_desc_blocks = 1, new_desc_blocks = 58
The filesystem on /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv is now 120784896 (4k) blocks long.

# Finally, you can check that you now have available space:
$ df -h
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                               3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                              786M  1.2M  785M   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv  454G  3.8G  432G   1% /
```

If you didn't customize the LVM settings, the names for the volume group and logical volume should be the same as mine (`ubuntu-vg` and `ubuntu-lv` respectively).

If your partition is completely full, you could get a `no space left` error when trying to resize the logical volume like:

```sh
lvm> lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv
  /etc/lvm/archive/.lvm_computer: write error failed: No space left on device
```

The easiest way to fix this is by removing `apt` cache (it will get regenerated next time you do `apt update`), which should give you more than enough space to complete the operation:

```sh
$ rm -rf /var/cache/apt/*
```

Comment: perfect.. any idea why this happens? what should we have done on loggin in?

Comment: I would count this as major bug - but apparently the folks at Canonical don't since a fresh installation of an Ubuntu Server 18.04.2 installation has exactly the same "behavior".

Comment: Are you serious? How is this expected behavior? I landed here after just installing a fresh 18.04.2 and wondering why / is only 4Gigs.

Comment: I continue to visit this answer and will continue to do so as long as LVM doesn't allocate all of available disk space on a disk

Comment: @Plazgoth youp, you are right, I assume it's a bug. IMHO, expected behavior should be: take entire vm disk, then I increase disk size from hypervisor or add more drives to physical machine, then I use LVM to acquire additional space....

Comment: Thank a million. It's the first step: `lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv` that I was missing...

Comment: Worked as a charm in 2020! Thanks!!

Comment: Thank you so much! You´re a lifesaver!

Comment: I've been coming back to this answer for years now. Still an issue with 18.04.4 server. Thank you!

Comment: I'm getting: `Multiple VGs found with the same name: skipping ubuntu-vg
  Use --select vg_uuid=<uuid> in place of the VG name.` after the `lvm` command.
Any thoughts?

Comment: When I use the select command, it says lvextend: unrecognized option '--select'

Comment: Ok, I sorted it. Apparently, if you have multiple volumes plugged in, ubuntu will name them all the same VG. I had to unplug my other hard disks to resize the volume. I'm leaving my other comments up because they describe the issue I was having. Mods, remove if inappropriate.

Comment: Thank you for this, my sandbox is no longer throwing insidious disk space errors

Comment: Well, it is still a bug in Ubuntu Server 20.04 and I keep still coming back to this answer. Thank you for this info.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. All my VMs created with Ubuntu 20.04 still have 4GB disks in 2020 after install, sadly.

Comment: This worked beautifully. I didn't even need the backups I saved, no data loss. You sir are a gentleman and a scholar.

Comment: Thanks. I rarely use Ubuntu Server and usually go with Debian, but some hardware was giving me trouble with Debian and I couldn't for the life me figure out why my 1TB RAID was showing up as ~200GB in a df -h.  This sorted the problem out swimmingly.

Comment: Thanks for this, it's still an issue with Ubuntu 18.04.5

Comment: If I perform the steps given in answer, will there be any data loss?

Comment: @Mukesh no, no data loss at all

Comment: I ran into this issue while cloning my hard drive and this worked like a charm! Thanks.

Comment: Worked for ubuntu server 22. Thanks.

Comment: Still an issue with Ubuntu 22.04 and this answer still works.

Comment: I can confirm this works on Ubuntu Server 22.04.2 "LTS"

Comment: It indeed works under Ubuntu 22.04. But strange it's still not solved by default when using LVM

Comment: thanks for this answer, but i want to increase almost like 200 gb my total disk size is 426G but my /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv size is 61g.

Answer (score 6):

This is still relevant today. Ubuntu 22.04.

Example of fix:

[image: example of fix]

It's absolutely ridiculous that this isn't the default behavior. Of course I want my 2TB drive

### Commands below for copying and pasting without the failed commands. :)

```
ssh user@ipaddress
cd ~
df
```

(**Note the drive:** /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv)

**Escalate privilages into lvm:**

```
sudo lvm
```

**Run LV Extend:**

```
lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv
```

**Now exit:**

```
exit
```

**Then resize:**

```
sudo resize2fs /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv
```

**New found free space visualized:**

```
df -h
```

Comment: This answer would be much improved if you would write it up without the failed commands, not to mention that a picture is impossible to copy and paste CLI fragments from. Just a thought.

Comment: Fair enough, I'm new around here so...thanks.

Also added the commands.

Comment: Thank you for improving the site!

Answer (score 5):

Expected behavior on an LVM install is indeed the smaller partitions. The system creates minimal space waste on physical partition creation expecting you to customize and expand the LVM as needed, since the added partitions aren't necessary to the operating systems function, and users having additional storage space, quotas, and expansion is the point of having an on-the-fly expandable LV and VG

What it should do, however, is explain that better on install

Answer (score 3):

It appears that you need to extend your Logical Volume.

It can be a bit tricky but if you understand that there are 3 parts, it'll be much easier.

- Physical Volume (PV) => The physical space on a drive.
- Volume Group (VG) => An abstracted amount of drive space that can be split between multiple drives/devices.
- Logical Volume (LV) => The space that ubuntu "sees"

You'll need to extend your VG all the way across your 1TB Drive (or extend however much you want), then extend the Logical Volume group to take up that space.

[Technet has a nice writeup](https://www.tecmint.com/extend-and-reduce-lvms-in-linux/) that (if you follow carefully) you'll be able to follow and extend your drive.