# Ubuntu partition probably not used

Tags: 18.04, server, partitioning

I have 3 partitions in Ubuntu and I am trying to install Anaconda, that is pretty big, but my hard disk is 500GB. I receive an error saying that there is no space in my drive. I explored partitions and it seems the biggest partition /dev/sda3 is not mounted or anyway it seems is not used (not appearing in df).

- How can I start to use /dev/sda3 and continuing to work in my home
  directory?
- Could you please clarify my partition situation?
- Where all my application have been installed until now?

Thank you.

```
xxxx@xxxx-home:/$ sudo parted -l
Model: ATA Hitachi HTS54757 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 750GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB   537MB   fat32              boot, esp
 2      538MB   1612MB  1074MB  ext4
 3      1612MB  750GB   749GB


Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv: 4295MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags:

Number  Start  End     Size    File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  4295MB  4295MB  ext4



xxxx@xxxx-home:/$ lsblk
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0                       7:0    0  89.1M  1 loop /snap/core/8213
loop1                       7:1    0  89.1M  1 loop /snap/core/8268
sda                         8:0    0 698.7G  0 disk
├─sda1                      8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2                      8:2    0     1G  0 part /boot
└─sda3                      8:3    0 697.1G  0 part
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0     4G  0 lvm  /
sr0                        11:0    1  1024M  0 rom



xxxx@xxxxx-home:/$ df -i
Filesystem                         Inodes  IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev                              2030747    535 2030212    1% /dev
tmpfs                             2038604    855 2037749    1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv  262144 137988  124156   53% /
tmpfs                             2038604      1 2038603    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                             2038604      3 2038601    1% /run/lock
tmpfs                             2038604     18 2038586    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop1                          12842  12842       0  100% /snap/core/8268
/dev/loop0                          12842  12842       0  100% /snap/core/8213
/dev/sda2                           65536    299   65237    1% /boot
/dev/sda1                               0      0       0     - /boot/efi
tmpfs                             2038604     11 2038593    1% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: You apparently made iive difficult, and are using LVM (Logical Volume Manager) rather than regular partitions. This is something very powerful but also more complex. Look on how that works to resize/reorganize your storage (that is what it is designed for - being able to change storage allocation without having to repartition)

Comment: thank you, so basically this is the partition where I am working on: ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv and it is full because it has only 4GB allocated, ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv seems to be a sub-partition of sda3 and I can dynamically allocate space from sda3 to ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv? Is my understanding correct more or less?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you did not add sda3 to the volume group. So you'd need to:

Extend your volume group to include sda3 ("ubuntu--vg" is the volume group):

```
vgextend ubuntu--vg /dev/sda3
```

Check the new size of your volume group:

```
vgs
```

Extend your logical volume to the entire volume group space ("ubuntu--lv" is the logical volume):

```
lvextend -l 100%FREE /dev/ubuntu--vg/ubuntu--lv
```

Check the new size of your logical volume:

```
lvs
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I solved using the answer provided here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1106795/ubuntu-server-18-04-lvm-out-of-space-with-improper-default-partitioning it is very similar to your answer but I also had to run resize2fs /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv

Comment: Great! If i may, i recommend a great source of documentation on LVM from RedHat: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/5/html/logical_volume_manager_administration/index