# Can't solve the /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 100% space used problem Ubuntu Server 20.04 running on VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, lvm, resize

I've been hours trying to solve this issue and can't figure out what else to do

When i do df -h, this is what i see:

```
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                               7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs                              1.6G  1.2M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv  8.8G  8.3G  129M  99% /
tmpfs                              7.9G   16K  7.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                              7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2                          976M  198M  712M  22% /boot
/dev/loop0                          56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/1944
/dev/loop1                          56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/1932
/dev/loop2                          71M   71M     0 100% /snap/lxd/16922
/dev/loop4                          32M   32M     0 100% /snap/snapd/10707
/dev/loop3                          68M   68M     0 100% /snap/lxd/18150
/dev/loop5                          32M   32M     0 100% /snap/snapd/10492
tmpfs                              1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/1000
```

As you can see it is full , and i can't even do a mkdir

Apparenty there is a clean solution: [Ubuntu Server 18.04 LVM out of space with improper default partitioning](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1106795/ubuntu-server-18-04-lvm-out-of-space-with-improper-default-partitioning)

I've done it but it shows the following:

lvm> lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv
New size (2303 extents) matches existing size (2303 extents).

As you can see This is doing nothing so i tried another thing:

Now i'm trying to make more space on the disk, but also having trubles doing that, i've made another post: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=101457

Please help

Thank you in advantage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i solved it in this way:

The host where i had the problem was a VirtualBox VM Ubuntu Server 20.04 so i had to redimensionate the disk by:

```
VBoxManage modifymedium --resize 90000 /home/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx.vdi
```

Now i used Gparted live cd from [here](https://downloads.sourceforge.net/gparted/gparted-live-1.1.0-8-amd64.iso)

Used the tool to add the free space to sda

Now we can go again to the VM and make the steps from [Ubuntu Server 18.04 LVM out of space with improper default partitioning](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1106795/ubuntu-server-18-04-lvm-out-of-space-with-improper-default-partitioning)