# My ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv out of disk space

Tags: partitioning, lvm

I am out of disk space and have been trying for 2 day researching to expand my vda3
ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv into the vda 250GB slot using lvextend but it has not worked for me.
Could someone help me out here?  Thanks (unbuntu 18.04.)

```
root@unbuntuserver3:/# lsblk
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0                       7:0    0 32.3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/11402
loop1                       7:1    0 61.6M  1 loop /snap/core20/904
loop2                       7:2    0  348K  1 loop /snap/bpytop/216
sr0                        11:0    1  841M  0 rom
vda                       252:0    0  250G  0 disk
├─vda1                    252:1    0    1M  0 part
├─vda2                    252:2    0    1G  0 part /boot
└─vda3                    252:3    0   49G  0 part
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0   49G  0 lvm  /
```

I did a df -h and the 250 GB disk does not show:

```
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                               1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                              395M  1.1M  394M   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv   49G   46G  245M 100% /
tmpfs                              2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                              2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/vda2                          976M  146M  764M  16% /boot
tmpfs                              395M     0  395M   0% /run/user/1000
/dev/loop0                          33M   33M     0 100% /snap/snapd/11402
/dev/loop1                          62M   62M     0 100% /snap/core20/904
/dev/loop2                         384K  384K     0 100% /snap/bpytop/216
```

All running on a Qnap TS-453D,64-bit x86, Intel® Celeron® J4125 quad-core 2.0 GHz processor, 8GB Mem.  Using VirtualizationStation 3 VM, 6TB Disk Space Raid 5.

```
root@unbuntuserver3:/# pvs
  PV         VG        Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/vda3  ubuntu-vg lvm2 a--  <49.00g    0
root@unbuntuserver3:/# vgs
  VG        #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
  ubuntu-vg   1   1   0 wz--n- <49.00g    0
root@unbuntuserver3:/# lvs
  LV        VG        Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  ubuntu-lv ubuntu-vg -wi-ao---- <49.00g
root@unbuntuserver3:/#
```

FYI, I also added the extra 250GB of disk space via the virtual station settings. However, because the 250GB did not show in my df -h I sarted attempting the use of lvextend cmd. Which I found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1106795/ubuntu-server-18-04-lvm-out-of-space-with-improper-default-partitioning).

I am installing **ubuntu server 18.04.5** and for speed sake, without GUI installed. So cannot use GParted.

Comment: You can use GParted on a server without a GUI. For many disk operations you need to run GParted in a live environment. The Ubuntu live environment has a GUI and GParted. Perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Your 250GB disk only has about 50GB of partitions. You probably have about 200GB unallocated. This should be obvious if you open GParted. Assuming this is the case proceed as follows:

Make sure you backup any data you cannot afford to lose.

Follow this guide from the section below Logical Volume Extending https://www.tecmint.com/extend-and-reduce-lvms-in-linux/

Don’t forget to complete the resize2fs step.

If you need more help ask specific questions

Good luck