# No more free space on main partition

Tags: server, partitioning, mount, disk-usage

I start by saying i am a noob in Linux systems and the only reason i need help is because i built a home server to have a bit more complex developing environment plus the obvious benefits like media server and file storage.
I followed some online tutorials and everything was fine until yesterday when i installed cockpit in order to have some VM's running on it, when the system told me that there is no free space left. Therefore, i am sure something i did not do correctly since the SSD i have Ubuntu installed on has 256Gb, out of which, as far as i can see, only half is occupied.
To put things in perspective, i have one more 256Gb SSD (sdb) + one 2Tb HDD which (sdc) which are logically fused into /mnt/cloud which i use as media server
Can someone please guide me on how to fix this?

Thank you.

[Result of df -i](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZWXX.png)

[Result for sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9D6LJ.png)

Comment: OMG, no....20.04.  It's the latest version. I am changing the tag now. Thank you for pointing that out

Comment: Latest version?  The October release (20.10) came out later than the April (20.04) release so please avoid *incorrect* or vague terms

Answer (score 0):

Your answer only points out `df -i` which only tells you about inodes, not really space left. However, `df -h` will respond with space used.

If you're unsure which folder takes the most space, run:
`sudo du -sh /*` and enter deeper into the folders which seem to take the most.

My guess would be some logs were produced and eventually took too much space which I would expect to find either under /var folder or somewhere within the folder with your VM (probably your `~/` dir).

Comment: [Well that returned this][3]

[And fstab contains this, in case it helps][4]

[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSG20.png
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZ0NI.png

Comment: It is a bit odd, since that Media folder should be on my second SSD (partition sdb1)

Answer (score 0):

So basically the problem was exactly the one here:
[Ubuntu Server 18.04 LVM out of space with improper default partitioning](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1106795/ubuntu-server-18-04-lvm-out-of-space-with-improper-default-partitioning)

But i am still wondering why my sdb1 partition appears in my root Media folder