# LVM size only 4G than 52G but should be 200G

Tags: 18.04, partitioning, lvm

Hi had and still have some very strange problems with a Server Ubuntu 18 LTS and LVM

First only 4GB seemed to have been used while creating the host during setup, which was dedected much later after a year of use and lead to a full root drive.
The host has been provisioned 200G of space in VMware but the root used only 4G:

It looked something like this (Sadly I don't have the real numbers anymore for this first part this is more or less how I remember it):

```
root@somehostname:~# df -h --total
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                               1,9G     0  1,9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                              395M  6,1M  389M   2% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv  3,9G  3,9G     0 100% /
tmpfs                              2,0G     0  2,0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5,0M     0  5,0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                              2,0G     0  2,0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2                          976M  224M  685M  25% /boot
tmpfs                              395M     0  395M   0% /run/user/1000
/dev/loop2                          99M   99M     0 100% /snap/core/11081
/dev/loop1                         100M  100M     0 100% /snap/core/11167
```

I "fixed" that using the following commands but only gained 46G of space beside it stating it "changed from 52,75 GiB (13504 extents) to <199,00 GiB (50943 extents)":
(At this pointed I started copying every change I made so this are real numbers and results)

```
root@somehostname:/var/log# lvresize -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
  /etc/lvm/archive/.lvm_trac_2626_513583731: write error failed: No space left on device

root@somehostname:/var/log# resize2fs /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
resize2fs 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
Filesystem at /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv is mounted on /; on-line resizing required
old_desc_blocks = 1, new_desc_blocks = 7
The filesystem on /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv is now 13828096 (4k) blocks long.

 

root@somehostname:/var/log# lvresize -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
  Size of logical volume ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv changed from 52,75 GiB (13504 extents) to <199,00 GiB (50943 extents).
  Logical volume ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv successfully resized.

root@somehostname:/var/log# df -h --total
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                               1,9G     0  1,9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                              395M  6,1M  389M   2% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv   52G  3,9G   46G   8% /
tmpfs                              2,0G     0  2,0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5,0M     0  5,0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                              2,0G     0  2,0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0                          98M   98M     0 100% /snap/core/9993
/dev/sda2                          976M  224M  685M  25% /boot
tmpfs                              395M     0  395M   0% /run/user/1000
/dev/loop2                          99M   99M     0 100% /snap/core/11081
total                               60G  4,4G   53G   8% -

root@somehostname:/var/log# lvresize -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
  New size (50943 extents) matches existing size (50943 extents).

root@somehostname:/var/log# df -h --total
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                               1,9G     0  1,9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                              395M  6,1M  389M   2% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv   52G  3,9G   46G   8% /
tmpfs                              2,0G     0  2,0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5,0M     0  5,0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                              2,0G     0  2,0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0                          98M   98M     0 100% /snap/core/9993
/dev/sda2                          976M  224M  685M  25% /boot
tmpfs                              395M     0  395M   0% /run/user/1000
/dev/loop2                          99M   99M     0 100% /snap/core/11081
total                               60G  4,4G   53G   8% -
```

lvscan and pvscan state ~200G

```
lvscan
  ACTIVE            '/dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv' [<199,00 GiB] inherit
```

```
pvscan
  PV /dev/sda3   VG ubuntu-vg       lvm2 [<199,00 GiB / 0    free]
  Total: 1 [<199,00 GiB] / in use: 1 [<199,00 GiB] / in no VG: 0 [0   ]
```

vgscan states only one VG

```
vgscan
  Reading volume groups from cache.
  Found volume group "ubuntu-vg" using metadata type lvm2
```

anyone any ideas of what is goning on here? Why isn't it using all the space of the lvm ? What am I missing? Why was it using 4G to beginn with when it had 52,75 GiB and only uses this amount of space now beside it actually should use 199GiB

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you run the `resize2fs` command again?

```
resize2fs /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
```

Your post shows you

- used `lvextend` to extend the LV and it grew to `52,75 GiB (13504 extents)`
- used `resize2fs` to grow the file system to fill this space
- used `lvextend` to extend the LV again and it grew to `<199,00 GiB (50943 extents)`

However, you did **not** use `resize2fs` a second time.  I don't know why the first `lvextend` did not fill the space, but there may have been an error because of the lack of disk space.

If `resize2fs` does not work then you should post the output of `pvs`, `vgs`, and `lvs`

> Why was it using 4G to beginn with

This appears to be the default behavior.  There are a number of threads about this.  Here are a couple links

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/subiquity/+bug/1785321
- [Ubuntu Server 18.04 LVM out of space with improper default partitioning](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1106795/ubuntu-server-18-04-lvm-out-of-space-with-improper-default-partitioning)