# How to adjust the default volume size after installation of Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: filesystem, disk, disk-management, virtual-file-system

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 on VMWare recently. When I create the VM, I specify the disk as 1000GB. I go through the installation by all options kept default except I selected the docker package.
After installation, the file system is only 200GB. How to let my main file system take a major portion of the 1000GB of the virtual disk rather than only 200GB? The below screenshots are info from Disk: (My other questions are why there are 2 disks while I only created only one disk and where the swap partition is.)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I guess I have found the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1106795/ubuntu-server-18-04-lvm-out-of-space-with-improper-default-partitioning) for the main question. But why the other questions? Why 2 disks while I created only 1 disk? Where is the swap?

Answer (score 1):

**Q. Why 2 disks while I created only 1 disk?**

If you look at the descriptions for the devices, you will see:

- 1.1TB Hard Disk (the virtual disk you created)
- 215GB Block Device (a logical volume where the OS is installed)

You will want to boot the VM with the installation ISO and grow the volume to use the entire virtual disk. Be sure to do this while the volume is not mounted, otherwise you will not be able to resize it.

**Q. Where is the swap?**

Swap is generally handled by a file rather than a partition. You can care the details for the file by opening terminal and typing:

```
swapon -s
```

You will likely find that the swap file is on the 215GB logical volume.