# Extend partition size on ubuntu 20.04 on VMware

Tags: lvm, fdisk, parted

I have ubuntu 20.04 with 10gb HDD on VMware. I have exported it and move another VMWare.
I need to have more capacity on HDD so on VMWare, I extend the HDD to 20.

I used this link to add new space to partition num3.
https://serverfault.com/a/969087/591078

So on now I have on `lsblk` sda3:

[image]

Run fdisk:

[image]

on sda3 I have 19GB but on `df -h` :

[image]

So I do not get new space on my partition.

I try this:
https://askubuntu.com/a/1117523/399465

but I do not get it.