# df -h returns under 100GB for 1TB SSD

Tags: 22.04

## BACKGROUND

1. A new [1TB SSD](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07Y5VDNT9) was outfitted with 22.04 server.
2. I think pvscan indicates the SSD physical space is **928.46GB**:

   PV /dev/sda3   VG ubuntu-vg       lvm2 [<928.46 GiB / <828.46 GiB free]
   Total: 1 [<928.46 GiB] / in use: 1 [<928.46 GiB] / in no VG: 0 [0   ]
3. My limited understanding of the subject matter per [Andy's post](https://askubuntu.com/a/1107065/545291):

   - Physical Volume (PV) => The physical space on a drive.
   - Volume Group (VG) => An abstracted amount of drive space that can be split between multiple drives/devices.
   - Logical Volume (LV) => The space that ubuntu "sees"

## ISSUE

`df -h`

returns:

[image]

I would think that the Available space should total to slightly less than 1TB.The screenshot indicates available space is 86GB.  If the database grows and needs more than 86GB, do I have a problem and if yes, what needs to be done?  I would like the database to be able to access / use the entire SSD if it needs it.

pvdisplay & vgdisplay return:

```
user@mysql:~$ sudo pvdisplay
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sda3
  VG Name               ubuntu-vg
  PV Size               928.46 GiB / not usable 4.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes 
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              237685
  Free PE               212085
  Allocated PE          25600
  PV UUID               jPdsbk-LYcP-uAPA-9yNP-vyJ2-hCQn-otcxpn



user@mysql:~$ sudo vgdisplay
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               ubuntu-vg
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  2
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                1
  Open LV               1
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               <928.46 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              237685
  Alloc PE / Size       25600 / 100.00 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       212085 / <828.46 GiB
  VG UUID               YPWO13-whTj-QHxd-7G1a-xO7W-kSeJ-zuUVPp
```

## QUESTION

I think I need help interpreting the information returned: will MySQL have access to the 900+GB to store data or does a procedure need to be performed to enable access to the 900+GB?

Comment: Possibly the remaining ~900 GB is unallocated by the LVM. Use the `pvdisplay`, `vgdisplay`... commands as appropriate to find out.

Comment: If you just want to enxtend the root LV, then see [Ubuntu Server 18.04 LVM out of space with improper default partitioning](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1106795/ubuntu-server-18-04-lvm-out-of-space-with-improper-default-partitioning). However if you want to allocate the remainder for mysql more specifically you might want to consider creating a separate volume for /var

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and format with [code block]s